# PHP: filename without file extension- best way?

Tags: php

I am trying to pull the filename out of a directory without the extension.

I am kludging my way through with the following:

```
foreach ($allowed_files as $filename) { 
  $link_filename = substr(basename($filename), 4, strrpos(basename($filename), '.'));
  $src_filename = substr($link_filename, 0, strrpos($link_filename) - 4);
  echo $src_filename;
}
```

...But that can't work if the extension string length is more than 3.
I looked around in the PHP docs to no avail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

PHP has a handy [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function that does the legwork for you here:

```
foreach ($allowed_files as $filename) {
  echo pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}
```

Example:

```
$files = array(
  'somefile.txt',
  'anotherfile.pdf',
  '/with/path/hello.properties',
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
  $name = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
  echo "$file => $name\n";
}
```

Output:

```
somefile.txt => somefile
anotherfile.pdf => anotherfile
/with/path/hello.properties => hello
```

Comment: what is the difference between pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_BASENAME) and basename($filename) ?

Comment: Typo on my part. PATHINFO_BASENAME is same as basename(). It's PATHINFO_FILENAME you want (updated).

Comment: I think you also have a typo where you echo out- Should be $file => $name . "\n"; right?  Or can you use string representation of internal variables as such with PHP?

Comment: Hm; actually this doesn't seem to work for me.  I get nothing returned when I do the operation on either a string akin to the files array you posted *or* a parsed string of my choice including the file extention (i.e. "happy.jpg").

Comment: @jml: No, the above code is correct. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php, especially http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double for PHP string syntax.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
function file_extension($filename){
    $x = explode('.', $filename);
    $ext=end($x);
    $filenameSansExt=str_replace('.'.$ext,"",$filename);
    return array(
        "filename"=>$filenameSansExt,
        "extension"=>'.'.$ext,
        "extension_undotted"=>$ext
        );
}
```

usage:

```
$filenames=array("file1.php","file2.inc.php","file3..qwe.e-rt.jpg");
foreach($filenames as $filename){
    print_r(file_extension($filename));
    echo "\n------\n";

}
```

output

```
Array
(
    [filename] => file1
    [extension] => .php
    [extension_undotted] => php
)

------
Array
(
    [filename] => file2.inc
    [extension] => .php
    [extension_undotted] => php
)

------
Array
(
    [filename] => file3..qwe.e-rt
    [extension] => .jpg
    [extension_undotted] => jpg
)

------
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Good to know how to solve the problem with a custom function.

Answer (score 2):

list($file) = explode('.', $filename);

Comment: what about `blah.class.php` ?

Comment: hi dmitrig01- 
what is list($file) in this case?  any variable?

Comment: I would do it like this and remove the last element after the explode.

Comment: i don't know how to remove the last element.  can you post an example of how to use this syntax?

Comment: My code only preserves the first element. list($file) says "take the first element and put it in variable $file".

If you want all but the last element, use substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.'));

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$noExt = preg_replace("/\\.[^.]*$/", "", $filename);
```

Edit in response to cletus's comment:
You could change it in one of a few ways:

```
$noExt = preg_replace("/\\.[^.]*$/", "", basename($filename));

// or

$noExt = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\\\\\/]*$/", "", $filename);
```

*Yes, PHP needs regex literals...*

Comment: I found this to be the most useful, since you are operating on the string itself.  It seems like it can be very useful to take the regex approach when you know precisely what string it is that you have to modify.

Comment: -1 This is a good example of why you shouldn't reinvent the wheel of something PHP does with an inbuilt function. What about the string "/some/path.to/afile"?